# Location tracking - algorithm to find position at exact point in time based on later location readings

Tags: algorithm, gps, location

I want to know a user's location at a specific point in time, let's say T0.

At T0 I start location tracking (with GPS for example) and some seconds later (5", 10", ...) I get several readings having

- time
- latitude
- longitude
- accuracy
- speed
- bearing

like so:

- T0       : no position known
- T0 + 5"  : lat=Lat1, lon=Lon1, accuracy=Acc1, speed1=Sp1, bearing1=B1
- T0 + 10" : lat=Lat2, lon=Lon2, accuracy=Acc2, speed2=S2, bearing2=B2
- ...
- T0 + 30" : lat=Lat5, lon=Lon5, accuracy=Acc5, speed5=S5, bearing5=B5

Now, it is pretty straight forward to do this for a while, until accuracy is in the needed range. In my example, let's say at T0 + 30" this is the case.
But this only gives me the user's location at T0 + 30".

My question is: Is there an algorithm to get a position (latitude, longitude, accuracy) for T0, based on the readings.

Comment: Sounds like the typical statistics problem of curve fitting: drawing the best fitting line based on a number of points with a given uncertainty. Maybe the people on Cross-Validated can help you?

Comment: @m69 Thanks, but I don't need a line or path, I'm only interested in the original position at time T0.

Comment: Not with 100% accuracy.  Assuming that 5' means 5 minutes you can assume that from T0 to T0+5' they were heading in the same direction and speed as their bearing at T0+5'.  But that's only a guess, if they sped up, slowed down, or turned at all its wrong.  And in 5 minutes there's lots of time to do that.  Now if it was 5 seconds, you'd have a decently accurate guess.

Comment: I meant that if you have an estimate of the path, with certain points on it linked to certain times, you could find the point on it that corresponds to time T0. (But it is indeed more complicated than the standard 2D line or curve through a cloud of XY-points.)

Comment: @GabeSechan I'm sorry, I meant 5 seconds etc. (have corrected the question).